# why PySpark Groupby taking so long?

Tags: python, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

SparkVersion 3.0

I have tried various method in grouping the table and counting the distinct values or filtering the data.

Why is it taking so long to execute the groupby and count?

```
SiteName = df['20160201'].select('SiteName','Temperature')
SiteName_Group = SiteName.groupBy("SiteName")
SiteName_Group.count()
```

Comment: couple of a ideas: 1) you have a lot of data 2) you have a slow machine

Comment: Some other possibilities: 1) You have lopsided partitions (ie one or two machines have a ton of data and the others have very little) 2) Your number of partitions is significantly differ than your number of machines.

Comment: You could try a repartition to distribute a roughly equal number of records to each machine

Comment: =/ I see, I am running it on my local machine.

Comment: A repartition could still help if you have a partition size of more than 1